# Find multiple strings in file - Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to find multiple strings in a text file in perl. I am getting it to work successfully but it does not seem very efficient:

```
 open(FILE,"$in" . "testFile.txt");
 my @file = <FILE>;
 close FILE;

 if(grep{/test1/} @file){
    ...
 }elsif(grep{/test2/} @file){
    ...
 }elsif(grep{/test3/} @file){
    ...
 }
```

I create an array that holds the contents of the file then iterate through it 3 times. This does not seem efficient. Is there a way to get this in one if statement to reduce the iterations and the reuse of code in each statement?

Comment: *"but it does not seem very efficient"* Are you saying that it[s running too slowly for your purposes, or that it seems a lot of code? Have you heard of the `or` operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your strings don't cross line boundaries, you can read your file a line at a time, and test for all three strings at once

```
open my $fh, "${in}testFile.txt" or die $!;

while ( <$fh> ) {

    if ( /test1/ or /test2/ or /test3/ ) {
        # Do something
        last;
    }
}
```

you could collapse that into a single regex if you wish

```
if ( /test1|test2|test3/ ) { ...; last; }
```